# Why cant I calculate the mean?

Tags: r, list, histogram, mean, sapply

trying to create a table to calculate the mean of my data, but sapply won't work, it keeps giving me the error that 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

here's my code

```
#Question 1
set.seed(10000)

v <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)

lyst <- list()

for(i in v)
{
  for(j in v)
  {
    elementname <- paste0(as.character(i),"-",as.character(j))
    print(elementname)
    lyst[[elementname]] <- rgamma(10000,i,j)
  }
}
#Question 2
pdf("Histogr4m.pdf",width = 20, height = 10)
par(mfcol=c(7,7))
for(x in names(lyst))
{
  hist(lyst[[x]],
       xlab = "Value",
       main = paste("Alpha-Lambda:",x))
}
dev.off()

#Question 3

sampleMean <- sapply(lyst, colMeans)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the fact that `lyst` is a class list object. Thus, it might be a better approach to use `lapply` to apply a function to every element of this list. You can do that by using the following code:

```
sampleMean <- lapply(lyst, mean)
```

Comment: oh, that worked, but would you know how that get that output into a table of 7x7 rather than one long list

Comment: You could try something like `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sampleMean), nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))`. You just need to specify if the values should be filled by rows (`byrow = T`) or by columns (`byrow=F`).